# Can't delete between parts of InputPhone form

Tags: reactjs, forms, format

```
import React from 'react';
import { useForm, Controller } from 'react-hook-form';
import cl from './inputPhone.module.css';
import { Toaster } from 'react-hot-toast';
import { useContext } from 'react';
import Context from '../../scripts/Context';


const InputPhone= (props) =>{
    const {control} = useForm();
    const context = useContext(Context);


    return (
        <>
        <div><Toaster/></div>
            <Controller name="numbers"
                control={control}
                defaultValue=""
                rules={{
                    required: 'required field',
                    pattern: {
                        value: /^\+7 \(\d{3}\) \d{3} \d{2} \d{2}$/,
                        message: 'wrong number',
                    }
                }}
                render={({field}) => (
                    <input
                        style={props.styleInput} 
                        className={cl.input}
                        {...field}
                        maxLength={18} 
                        placeholder="+7 (___) ___ __ __"
                        onInput={(e) => {
                            const input = e.target.value.replace(/\D/g, '');
                            const parts = input.match(/^(\d{0,1})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,3})(\d{0,2})(\d{0,2})$/);
            
                            if (!parts) return;
                            
            
                            const formattedPhone = `+7 (${parts[2] || ''}) ${parts[3] || ''} ${parts[4] || ''} ${parts[5] || ''}`;
                            e.target.value = formattedPhone;
                            context.setTelValue(e.target.value);
                        }}
                    />
                )}
            />        
        </>
    );
};

export default InputPhone;
```

I can't delete numbers between parts with backspace nor delete. It can delete only in it's segment.
Example: I typed in to the end, and want to erase - I press backspace and can delete only 2 last numbers.

Even chatgpt couldn't understand me